# If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that [C++]

Tags: c++

The code that I did was for solving the following problem. However, the logic of the code is wrong and I as a good newbie cannot figure what is wrong. 
After I compile the result of 'sum' is always 0, if I change the initialization of 'sum' for a whatever number, that whatever number is what appear as answer of 'sum'.

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    long sum = 0;

    for( long i; i < 1000; ++i )
    {
        if (( i % 3 == 0 ) || ( i % 5 == 0 ))
        {   
            sum = sum + i;
        }

    }
cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What warnings does the compiler give you? Warnings are your friend. The compiler can tell you what you are doing wrong. It will in this case.

Comment: FWIW this problem is easier to solve with a pen and paper than with code. Step 1: Find a formula for "the sum of all multiples of N below 1000". Step 2: If formula F is the formula for step 1, compute F(3) + F(5) - F(15)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `i` in your loop:

`for (long i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )`

As it is, i is probably some random number greater than 0 at the top of the loop, and the result is that the loop is never executed.

Comment: Hey Craig, may I encourage you to look at my answer to this question? Please don't take it personally :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `i` to zero otherwise `i`'s value will be whatever happens to be in memory. In this case it's > 1000.

`for (long i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)`

Also, a nice trick I learned. Use `ii` as your index variable. It's much easier to find `ii` than just `i` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set i=O in your loop so the loop won't iterate.

Answer (score -1):

All answers above are correct - you need to set your `i` to `0`. What you might be interested in is that accessing uninitialized variable is an "undefined behaviour" (UB) and modern compilers are actually pretty good in finding the UBs and using them to optimize the code. For example, GCC 5.2 with `-O2` (optimizations enabled) will generate *same* assembly for your code and for one without the loop *at* *all* regardless of what might happen to be in the memory at the address of `i`.

Try putting this code to (which is your code with additional `#if` for convenience) [this online disassembler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
        long sum = 0;

  #if 1
        for (long i; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }

        }
  #endif
        cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

add the `-O2` flag to compiler options on top right and try changing `#if 1` to `#if 0` and observe that the disassembly is the same meaning that the compiler cut out the loop completely.

Comment: The downvote was because the answer part of your answer is "everyone else is correct" and the extra stuff is irrelevant to the question. And you specifically invited me to review your answer. So I did.

Comment: @Craig Well, I agree with "everyone else is correct part" - this is not a part of the good answer. However, given that the OP always gets 0 in `sum` - I'm pretty sure it's because the compiler optimized the loop away completely due to UB - not because `i` is some random value. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Based on `sum` == 0, we can't tell if the loop never executed because its terminal condition was met or if it was optimized out. The latter behavior would be pointless because it doesn't address the problem in the code. That is, if the compiler wants to be helpful, rather than optimizing away the error, it should point it out. Given the code as-is, it cannot be the programmer's intention that the loop not be executed (such as could be the case if the control variable was not declared inside the loop). So assuming the compiler behaves rationally, it is more likely the loop condition is met.

Comment: ...in any case, it is irrelevant to the answer. Consider the possibility that stray alpha particles struck the processor at just the right time to cause `sum` to be zero. Or consider the possibility that a virus overwrote the loop in memory. While these are possibilities, they don't address the more likely problem here, which is a very, very obvious error in the initialization of the loop control variable. Fix that error and every other point being made in your answer is moot. I apologize for belaboring this point, but you requested the critique in your comment on my answer. :-)